# Explanation of this C Program

Tags: c

Considering 64 bit

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    unsigned a=0xffffffff;

    a=~a;

    printf("%u\n",a);

    printf("%x\n",+  +  a);
    return 0;

}
OUTPUT:
0
0
```

after  taking ~a , a is now 0. but in statement "+ + a". "a" is not incrementing why? does space matters here or what ? 
**i am asking for output explanation ?**

Comment: Yes, spaces matter, they separate tokens. `++` is one token, `+ +` are two.

Comment: Yes, if you meant `++a`, that's not what you wrote.

Comment: C tokens are parsed using the "maximum munch" rule. A munch ends at a whitespace (unless the whitespace is part of a literal).

Comment: @Nirk yes i saw your answer ! space matters here !

Comment: @NatashaAlyshayaRubenko Space matters, so make sure to **format your code well.**

Comment: @H2CO3 space doesn't always matter, but in this case it does

Comment: @H2CO3 - yeah i will keep that in my mind ! thanks for Advice!

Comment: @Nirk (you teachin' me C? Am I seeing that correctly?)

Comment: @NatashaAlyshayaRubenko [Some sane guidelines](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) for success.

Comment: @H2CO3 - link is of ios ?? weird ? i don't understand ?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes :)  I'm niggling.  The statement "space matters" elicits thoughts of languages like coffeescript where interstitial whitespace does actually matter.  But `b = ++ a` is the same as `b=++a` in C

Comment: @NatashaAlyshayaRubenko Sorry, fixed the link.

Comment: @Nirk - H2CO3 is more experienced than you ! please bare that in mind before messing on something!

Comment: @Nirk I know all that.

Comment: @H2CO3 - that is so perfect link ! thanks a million for that !

Comment: @NatashaAlyshayaRubenko Welcome. Read and embrace those, the best C coding style I've used so far. (Well, it's Linus', anyway, no surprise...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+ + a` is parsed as the unary `+` operator applied twice, so the value remains unchanged.

`+(+a)` is what the compiler saw, which is just 0 in this case

Answer (score 6):

I think both plus are acting as unary operator here. "Since + and - both can act as unary operator.", so here no effect on "a". it remains 0.

if ++a; then this is prefix increment operator and "a" will become 1.